# Get new texfield input with bar code scanner flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Working on a desktop application. I have an external bar code scanner which scans bar code and writes the value in any text field.

Now I have a textfield which does 2 job, search by name and search by barcode.

```
  Widget _buildSearch() {
    return Container(
      height: 35,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: TextField(
        textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
        controller: _searchController,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
        autofocus: true,
        focusNode: _searchFocusNode,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          hintText: "Search",
          hintStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
        ),
        onChanged: (value) {
          _handleOnChanged(value);
        },
        onSubmitted: (value) {
          
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

`_handleOnChanged` is simple:

```
  _handleOnChanged(String value) {
    setState(() {
      _isSearching = true;
    });
    _products = _productsList.search(value); //_products is a List<Product>
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        _isSearching = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

What I want is to add some sort of listener to the textfield so whenever the user scans a new search will be initiated.

SO let's say the user scans a bar code whose value is `GR13`, a product has been found. Now if the user scans again the textfield should be cleared and the new bar code will be scanned.

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

normally the scanners will send submit signal after reading the code, which in your case is 'Enter'. so you could implement onSubmitted to pass the value or call a method that will get _searchController.text

then it will initiate a _searchController.clear()

Comment: So onchanged for usual searchbyname and onsubmitted for barcode input? But after a sucessfull search by barcode how can I make the textfield ready for another search? RequestFocus?

Comment: the same method that will clear the textfield can do _searchFocusNode.requestFocus()

Comment: so in short, _onSubmitted will do: `search()`, `_controller.clear()` and `_searchFocusNode.requestFocus()`
Thanks I'm gonna give it a try